# How to use a string in the array?

Tags: php, arrays, string

My array is:

```
$myarray = array(
    'first_id' => 1111,
    'second_id' => 2222
);
```

And my strings are:

```
$first_id = "1111";
$second_id = "2222";
```

And I want to use this array like the following example:

```
$myarray = array(
    'first_id' => $first_id,
    'second_id' => $second_id
);
```

But it won’t work. How do I use strings in the array?

Sincerely.

Comment: That works fine. What is the problem?

Comment: What is it that does not work? Your syntax is valid to define an array using those variables.

Comment: I dont know why it doesnt work, But it works fine with xdazz's answer. Ty for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, but if you want to cast to integer, then just:

```
$myarray = array('first_id' => (int)$first_id, 'second_id' => (int)$second_id);
```